# How can a service be executed without an executable on Windows?

Tags: windows, service, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, startup

I was reading an [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1353485819300716) about a [malware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/emotet/).

An when describing its installation process I came across the following question:

How can a program run on startup if there is no script or executable file present in the system?

The only similar question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347101/can-there-be-a-process-without-an-executable-backed-image) but it does not mention a system reboot.

Here is how the article described the installation process of the malware (paraphrased in my own words):

> Let's say there is a malicious .exe file in a Windows computer.
>
> When executed it starts a process which creates a Mutex and some Events then injects itself into another program's memory space and kills its own process.
>
> **After this setup phase the original malicious .exe is deleted from the hard drive.**
>
> A process is started to check whether the Mutex is present if not then it will startup the malware.
>
> The Task Scheduler is used so that when the infected computer starts up the malware is executed.
>
> It can also set up a Windows Service for the malware.

Comment: Haven't read the article, but there are several executables/facilities in Windows that will happily run an arbitrary function from an arbitrary user provided DLL. Rundll, svchost, dllhost, powershell, to name a few.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev could you provide more information about this? Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the first place? StackOverflow is for specific questions, not a "do my research for me" place.

Comment: After reading the article this was the only thing which I did not understand and would like some clarification on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Here's one example. Put togerther a .NET DLL, run the following command `powershell -Command "Add-Type -Path MyDLL.dll"`. That will load your DLL and execute its startup code. Task accomplished, a piece of your code was run without an executable.

Comment: This clarifies it a lot, thank you.

Comment: As for svchost, read up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost.exe). Same idea - package your code in a DLL, have a Windows built-in facility load and run it.

Comment: @sev: `MyDLL.dll` *is* an executable. Unless it's a resource-only DLL. Regardless, though, PowerShell.exe is an executable.

Comment: The point of the OP's question, as far as I understand, was - how can the malware run its code without an .exe? I've answered that.